# XSLT 1.0: selecting based on attribute of preceding siblings of current() node

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a base xml file like:

```
<base>
     ...
     <s l="something" />
     <s l="somethingelse" />
     <s>
     ...
</base>
```

In my xslt, I use the `document()` function on each `<s>` to pull in another file structured like:

```
<otherbase>
     ...
     <r l="something" />
     <r l="somethingelse" />
     <r l="evenmore" />
     ...
</otherbase>
```

At `<s>` in the base file, I am trying to select all `<r>`s whose `@l` does not match *any* `preceding-sibling::*/@l` of the current `<s>`. Thus for the third `<s>` with no attribute, it would match `<r l="evenmore" />` etc.

Something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('mydoc.xml')//r[@l != preceding-sibling::*/@l]"> 
     ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

would work if I were matching within the `<r>` attributes I believe, but I need preceding-siblings of `current()` ... I haven't been able to figure out the syntax.

Unfortunately there are no 2.0 processors in my environment, stuck in xslt 1.0.

Comment: I changed your title because your question has nothing to do with pattern matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `current()` function when you want to refer to the current `s` node within a predicate. Try:

```
select="document('mydoc.xml')//r[not(@l = current()/preceding-sibling::s/@l)]"
```

Note also the difference between `$a != $b` and `not($a = $b)`.